Isomorphism between the reduced C*-algebra of a groupoid and the crossed product of inverse semigroups
In Paterson's book "Groupoids, Inverse Semigroups and their Operator Algebras" he proves that for any r-discrete groupoid $G$ with unit space $G^0$, its full $C^* $-algebra $C^* (G)$ is isomorphic to $C_0(G^0) \rtimes_\beta S$ for a suitable inverse subsemigroup $S \subseteq G^{op}$ ($G^{op}$ is the inverse semigroup of open bisections of $G$) and canonical action $\beta$, where the crossed product is taken in the sense of Sieben in "$C^* $-crossed products by partial actions and actions of inverse semigroups".
I am looking for a similar result but in the reduced case. Sieben did not define the reduced crossed product $A \rtimes_{\beta,r} S$ so a reference for the development of such an object is already very appreciated.
With this in mind, the main question (or reference request) is if there is a definition of $A \rtimes_{\beta,r} S$ that gives the existence of an isomorphism
$$
C_r^* (G) \cong C_0(G^0) \rtimes_{\beta,r} S
$$
with $S$ in the same conditions as above?

This is developed in several papers of Buss, Exel, Meyer and Kwaśniewski, but I think Sections 2 and 4 of my paper with Buss is a nice summary:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0001870823003948?via%3Dihub
The literature in the previous papers is somewhat scattered.

By the way, the isomorphism is just the same map, which is continuous both in the max norm, the reduced one, and the "essential" one (the latter only being different from the reduced for non-Hausdorff groupoids).

@DiegoMartinez Thank you so much! I looked in the article and the idea is that to an action of inverse semigroups by partial automorphisms (like sieben does) corresponds a Fell bundle?

@DiegoMartinez I have been trying to make that bridge. If we denote de action by $\beta$ and for all $s \in S$ the domain of $\beta_s$ (which is an ideal in A) by $A_s$ then I want to turn $\mathcal{A} = {A_s}$ to a Fell bundle correct? I can induce an $A$-$A$-bimodule structure on $A_s$ by multiplication, however it poses a problem (see next comment).

@DiegoMartinez The problem is that we would want the embeddings $\mu_{s,t}: A_s \otimes_A A_t \rightarrow A_{st}$ to be defined by:  $$\mu_{s,t}(a_s \otimes a_t) = \beta_s(\beta_{s^*}(a)b), $$ but these fail to be $A$-bimodular. I thought about changing the $A$-bimodule structure on $A_s$ in order to make the $\mu_{s,t}$ bimodule maps but I am not succeeding.

Yes, the idea is to construct a Fell bundle (but you don't really need to, since Fell bundles are much more general). In any case, elements $s \in S$ are open bisections of $G$, and $A_s = C_0(s)$, which will be embedded into $C^*(G)$ in the usual way (similarly for the reduced and essential). The formula that you want should then be that the product of $a_s$ and $a_t$ looks like $[gh \mapsto a_s(g) a_t(h)]$, where $g \in s, h \in t$ (and thus $gh \in st$). This should be the formula I think you meant to write:
$ \mu_{s, t}(a_s \otimes a_t) = \beta_s(\beta_{s^*}(a_s)a_t)$

In any case, the isomorphism you're looking for can be written down for the dense subalgebras. Any $f \in C_c(G^0) \rtimes_{alg} S$ can be written (by definition) as a finite linear combination
$f = f_{s_1} + \dots + f_{s_k}$
where $f_{s_i}$ is a function on $G$ that is continuous and supported on the open bisection $s_i$. Then this map is continuous in the max norm, in the reduced one, and also in the essential seminorm (this is only a seminorm in general).

@DiegoMartinez I am struggling a little to understand what is the reduced norm on $C_c(G^0) \rtimes_{alg} S$. If $\mathcal{A}$ is the Fell Bundle associated with the action, is the Hilbert Space $\ell^2(\mathcal{A}'')$ of Definition 3.2 of the article isometrically isomorphic to $L^2(G)$ viewed as a $C_0(X)$-module? I am sorry for this many questions, I am doing my master thesis so I'm not very comfortable yet with some of the machinery in the article.

@DiegoMartinez I asking this because I do not understand very well the weak conditional expectation $P$ of Definition 2.25. In the case that $G$ is Hausdorff, is it the one corresponding to the extension of the restriction map $C_c(G) \rightarrow C_c(G^0)$?
